# Decodificar Boletos

Tags: php, boleto, boletophp

Boa noite amigos,

Preciso desenvolver um script para decodificar a linha digitável de um boleto em PHP, para minha surpresa não achei nada pré-feito sobre isso, ja para a codificação da linha existem dezenas de scripts. Eu poderia fazer uma adaptação utilizando um script de codificação seguindo o caminho inverso, mas meu script ainda ficaria incompleto para a decodificação de contas de luz, agua, telefone, etc. E pelas informações que coletei algumas empresas não seguem o padrão normal para emissão da linha, o que pode dificultar ainda mais.

A minha pergunta é, alguém tem alguma solução para me indicar? Eu preciso do vencimento, nome da empresa e valor, na verdade gostaria também de poder verificar se o boleto esta registrado, mas isso parece ser impossível então já desisti. Não consegui achar nem uma API que forneça esse serviço.

Comment: Como você está tentando fazer? Você está lendo a imagem do boleto ou apenas o código de barras? Já tentou através de [*OCR*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconhecimento_%C3%B3tico_de_caracteres)?

Comment: Quando você diz "decodificar" a linha digitável você quer dizer "montar" a linha?

Comment: Eu acho que entendi o que quer. Você quer digitar o código de barras (digitar ou usar um leitor) e separar CNPJ, VENCIMENTO, VALOR, assim terá uma relação disso tudo. Mas, no código de barras não consta CNPJ ou CPF, então já não dará certo. Existem diversas partes livres na composição, mas não se tem padrão. [Exemplos](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+c%C3%B3digo+de+barras+boleto&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiexcHg5d_cAhXGhpAKHc2fBmIQ_AUICygC&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=uFKin-ITChLzzM:)

Comment: Acredito que você não consiga extrair tudo isso a partir do código de barras. O que você consegue é identificar o código do banco que emitiu o boleto e, assim, consultar no serviço dele os dados do boleto. Se me lembro bem, vive só consegue extrair o código do banco, a moeda, data de vencimento e valor total. Qualquer outra informação acredito que venha do serviço do banco emissor.

Comment: Por que então qdo coloco no internet banking a conta de água ele consegue identificar até a empresa que emitiu o boleto ?

Comment: @PedroAugusto porque são todos registrados. Existe um código único (alguns chamam de "nosso número") do banco referente ao boleto, assim quando consulta, ele já tem o registro interno. Hoje, por lei, todos os boletos devem ser registrados, ou seja, quem gera o boleto tem que enviar um arquivo ao banco para registrá-los.